# onClick method does not exist

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

(!)`onClick` method does not exist

> Corresponding method handler 'public void navigate(android.view.View)' not found  The onClick attribute value should be the name of a method in this View's context to invoke when the view is clicked. This name must correspond to a public method that takes exactly one parameter of type View.  Must be a string value, using '\;' to escape characters such as '\n' or '\uxxxx' for a unicode character.

*
Hello I am new here, I am simply trying courses on Coursera but it seems like it's pretty outdated, and some things are not working properly as it is supposed to. 
I have been trying to search here on the forums to find an answer, and I have tried a couple of things, but it seems like I am too retarded and a newbie.
Could it be something to do with my tools:context?

**Heres my xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
tools:context="MainActivity"
android:background="#ffffff">


<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/numberPicker"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="navigate"/>

<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

**Heres my java:**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

NumberPicker possibilities;
WebView webView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    possibilities = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    String[] possibilitiesStrings = {
            "Android",
            "Checklist text-input fields",
            "Coursera",
            "Supelec",
    };
    possibilities.setDisplayedValues(possibilitiesStrings);
    possibilities.setMinValue(0);
    possibilities.setMaxValue(possibilitiesStrings.length - 1);

    /**
     * called when the OK button from activity_main.xml is clicked
     * @param v the View which triggered the method call: the OK button
     */
    public void navigate(View v) {
    int choice = possibilities.getValue();
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    if (choice == 0)
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/android.html");
    else if (choice == 1)
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/checklist.html");
else if (choice == 2)
    webView.loadUrl("http:///www.coursera.org");
else if (choice == 3)
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/supelec.html");
}

}


}
}
```

Comment: Dude, this a fantastic example of a good question, especially from a first poster. Solid job!

Answer (score 2):

I analyzed your code and I see you declare your navigate method in your `onCreate() method` so is why you can find it from xml.

Example how declare method to use in xml

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    NumberPicker possibilities;
    WebView webView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        possibilities = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        String[] possibilitiesStrings = {
                "Android",
                "Checklist text-input fields",
                "Coursera",
                "Supelec",
        };
        possibilities.setDisplayedValues(possibilitiesStrings);
        possibilities.setMinValue(0);
        possibilities.setMaxValue(possibilitiesStrings.length - 1);

    }

    /**
     * called when the OK button from activity_main.xml is clicked
     * @param v the View which triggered the method call: the OK button
     */
    public void navigate(View v) {
        int choice = possibilities.getValue();
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        if (choice == 0)
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/android.html");
        else if (choice == 1)
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/checklist.html");
        else if (choice == 2)
            webView.loadUrl("http:///www.coursera.org");
        else if (choice == 3)
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/supelec.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but what do you mean about declaring the method in XML? What can I do to make navigate work and "View v" ?

Comment: how can you give me an example, when it's the exact same code I used?